# How to read iBooks offline

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, ibook

I can't figure out how to download a book to my iPhone 7 iOS 13.6 that's currently stored in iCloud.

How can I download the book so that I can read it offline later?

Comment: Did you download the books app ?

Comment: @anki yes (I did download the Books app)

Comment: Oh now I understand. you cannot make sure that the book will stay downloaded offline if sync is turned on. Either turn off sync, or keep the iPhone online all the time

Comment: @anki I checked in my downloaded books collection, and  it said the book was there. I just turned off iCloud Drive and Reading Now syncing in iBooks in settings, and now the book doesn't even appear in the downloaded collection.  It says I have no downloaded Books

Comment: `~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/` Find all the books in this folder and airdrop them to the iPhone. That's the only way I found that keeps books offline on iPhone. Or use another app.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on the book of interest and you get a menu of options. Under 'share', there is an option to email the book. You can email the book to yourself and then save it on your iPhone.

Comment: This works only for imported PDFs. On Mac, other books (files) can be found in `/Users/me/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents/`

Comment: on my computer, it works for Books and PDFs. I just tried it on a novel I downloaded and it worked fine.  But your method is much better.